# Network, improve connecting time

Tags: performance, http

I noticed that the connecting time for my site is slower than for the other sites that I have tried. 100 - 200 ms.

I am referring to the connecting time on the Network tab (dns lookup, connecting,waiting, etc.)

How can I improve it? Is it just something that is controlled by my host (Webfaction) or can I change some settings? I am the only person on my site at this time. DNS lookup is fast, not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Site opening slow for that there are so many reason or parameter affect.

1. Bandwidth on server.
2. traffic on Server in term of request with its data size.
3. some Network issue like DNS is resolving your query quite slow. (use 4.2.2.2 or 8.8.8.8 DNS server)
4. Last but not have much probability that some on attack on network of doing flooding.

my suggestion to verify your Server Bandwidth and new HTTP connections per second.
also look that some uploading or downloading is going on or not.